# Mapping function to numpy array, varying a parameter

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, numpy, currying

First, let me show you the codez:

```
a = array([...])
for n in range(10000):
    func_curry = functools.partial(func, y=n)
    result = array(map(func_curry, a))
    do_something_else(result)
    ...
```

What I'm doing here is trying to apply `func` to an array, changing every time the value of the `func`'s second parameter. This is SLOOOOW (creating a new function every iteration surely does not help), and I also feel I missed the pythonic way of doing it. Any suggestion?

Could a solution that gives me a 2D array be a good idea? I don't know, but maybe it is.

Answers to possible questions:

- Yes, this is  (using a broad definition), an optimization problem (`do_something_else()` hides this)
- No, scipy.optimize hasn't worked because I'm dealing with boolean values and it never seems to converge.

Comment: What does func do? If we know more of what it does then we can maybe help you find a faster way to do it. Right now, I think that map is having to change numpy array to a list, map it, and then the list is being changed back to an array which doesn't sound fast to me. If we can find a way to do func to the columns using numpy functions, it should be faster. I'm guessing that you are applying func on each column of the matrix in a and then using the result to move closer to the correct solution. Have you profiled to make sure that this part is the problem and not the do_something_else part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try `numpy.vectorize`?

```
...
    vfunc_curry = vectorize(functools.partial(func, y=n))
    result = vfunc_curry(a)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is of significant size the bottleneck should not be the creation of the function, but the duplication of the array.

Comment: `a` is an 1D numpy array of length 100

Comment: so what das `func` do? If you cannot reveal what `func` does for some reason you have to search for the bottleneck for yourself. A Profiler will help with that (http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you rewrite the function? If possible, you should write the function to take two numpy arrays `a` and `numpy.arange(n)`. You may need to reshape to get the arrays to line up for broadcasting.